# Is it possible to use Emacs to read mail using IMAP without downloading them?

Tags: mu4e, email, remote, imap

I have found that Emacs + mu4e + offlineimap can deal with reading emails from a remote server. However, in this case, what I understand is that the emails are copied locally. Having mailboxes with lots of messages I do not want them to use hard disk space.

Did I misunderstand the way offlineimap works or is there another solution to what I want to do ?

I am new to Emacs, thanks in advance.

Comment: mu4e is the human interface to a mu database, which reads a maildir to index it. AFAIK all readers use the same approach, call it local mailboxes or call it cache. With mu/mu4e you will always have the stuff locally even if you can make it indexing just reading it from the remote server. I'm not aware of web-like imap clients for emacs, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are open to using something other than `mu4e` you can use `gnus` to read email via IMAP without storing messages locally.  Searching can be a little slow, for me taking one or two seconds on folders with several thousand entries, but that's acceptable to me.  Be warned that the learning curve for `gnus` is fairly steep.

Comment: Thank you very much !